# JVM ignoring Xms setting

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I have the following Java program that I don't expect to need much java heap:

#### SleepTest.java

```
public class SleepTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore I try to inform this to the JVM by specifying an initial heap size using the `Xms` setting. However it seems that the JVM just ignores this and allocates with the default size. Why is this ?

To illustrate I start my program three times:

```
abc@yyy:~> java SleepTest &                       // default - 512 MB
[1] 15745
abc@yyy:~> java -Xms10M SleepTest &               // specifying initial size of 10 MB
[2] 15756
abc@yyy:~> java -Xmx10M SleepTest &               // forcing max heap size of 10 MB
[3] 15766
```

And investigates the memory consumption in Linux:

```
abc@yyy:~/ebbe> grep VmSize /proc/15745/status /proc/15756/status /proc/15766/status
/proc/15745/status:VmSize:        688828 kB       // default
/proc/15756/status:VmSize:        688892 kB       // specifying initial size of 10 MB
/proc/15766/status:VmSize:        166596 kB       // forcing max heap size of 10 MB
```

Here the size of process **15756** indicates that it just allocated the same as default.

I'm using the following JVM:

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460sr16fp1-20140706_01(SR16 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux amd64-64 jvmxa6460sr16-20140626_204542 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20140626_204542
JIT  - r9_20130920_46510ifx7
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20140626_1848_B204542)
JCL  - 20140704_01
```

And I'm running on

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3
```

Comment: -Xms is a hint, one which the JVM is free to ignore.  I tested using Ubuntu, and Java 1.7.0_51 and got 1713284 kB and 18778124 kB respectively.  I also repeated using 1.6.0_25, and got the same result.  18188844 kb.

Answer (score 2):

The VM does honor the -Xms hint, but if you set it too low, the heap will immediately grow to satisfy allocation requests.

You conclude your code "doesn't need much memory" based on what's in your code. You do not take into account the memory consumed by the startup of the VM/JRE. Beware that due to the dependencies the VM has to load a lot of the JRE classes before it even begins executing your code.

The -Xms option is meant to ensure that the VM allocates *at least* as much heap, its the *lower limit* for the heap size. The VM is always free to allocate more. Thats where -Xmx comes into the picture (to define the *upper limit*).

Comment: I do understand that other stuff happens besides my code, and that also uses memory - but that do not explain why it allocates the full 512 MB. I just ran it with -Xms300M and it still used a 512 MB heap.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen The VM uses some method to determine how much to increase heap size when the current heap is to small, the formula probably varies from VM to VM version, an other factors; like the presence/absence of a max heap limit, available memory on host etc. In a virtual on demand memory environment allocating, but not accessing memory is dead cheap, so there is no particular incentive to be scroogy about it.